# VPD Policy Function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to oracle security and I have a question about Virtual Private Database:
Let's assume i have the following table which is called "Payroll" created by a user called "PCM"

```
EMP_ID               DEPT                      TOTAL      TAXES
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
E1                   accounting                 2400        100 
E2                   sales                      2500         75 
E3                   research                   3000        110 
E4                   operations                 4200        120 
E5                   sales                      4800        130 
E6                   sales                      2500         75 
E7                   accounting                 5200        140 
E8                   accounting                 2700        105
```

Now what i want to achieve is the following: Anyone with the `dept = accounting"` can select all other rows with `dept != accounting` but anyone with `dept != accounting` can only view his/her record.
My problem is: since we can't apply a select statement on the table we are restricting the access to inside the policy function (which is payroll) and since applying a policy function on the (payroll) table will be applied to any view based on it, what's the logic to solve this problem?? what is the solution, I've wrote the following "I'm connected as another user not the owner of the payroll table so I'm connected as a user called ANNE":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT payroll_ctx USING payroll_ctx_pkg;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE payroll_ctx_pkg IS 
  PROCEDURE set_dept;
 END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY payroll_ctx_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE set_dept
  AS
    v_dept varchar2(400);
  BEGIN
     SELECT dept INTO v_dept FROM PCM.PAYROLL
        WHERE EMP_ID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');
     DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept', v_dept);
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept', 'E0');
  END set_dept;
END;
/
```

Considering that the users who will try to access the table have the names of the emp_id column,now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_dept_trig AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
 BEGIN
  ANNE.payroll_ctx_pkg.set_dept;
 END;
/
```

Now the problem(i know it's wrong) but can't find the solution:

```
create or replace function sec_fun (p_schema varchar2, p_obj varchar2)
return varchar2
as
    vv_dept varchar2(400);
    payroll_pred varchar2(400);
begin
    payroll_pred := '1=2';
    vv_dept := SYS_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept');
    if (vv_dept != 'accounting') then
        payroll_pred := 'DEPT =''' || vv_dept ||'''';
    else
        payroll_pred:='DEPT !=''' || vv_dept ||'''';
    end if;
   return payroll_pred;
end;
/
```

And then:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
  object_schema    => 'PCM', 
  object_name      => 'PAYROLL', 
  policy_name      => 'payroll_policy', 
  function_schema  => 'ANNE',
  policy_function  => 'sec_fun',
  statement_types  => 'select');
END;
/
```

and the error message i'm getting when a user E1 tries to select from payroll:

```
no rows selected
```

what i'm doing wrong??
I have edited the question and the result based on the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some guesses but if none of them solve your problem you will need to look for the diagnostic information the database provides. ORA-28112 will produce a trace file in the `user_dump_dest` directory on the database server. This should give you all the information you need to diagnose and fix any errors in your policy code. If you don't have access to that directory you will need to ask your friendly DBA/Sysadmin team to help.

So, the guesses.

You're setting `vv_dept` to a string of `'dept = SYS_CONTEXT(''payroll_ctx'', ''dept'')'`. In the IF block you concatenate that to a WHERE clause filter. So your final string is actually:

```
DEPT =dept = SYS_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept')
```

(It will never execute `DEPT !=` branch because you're assigning that string to `vv_dept` not executing it, so `vv_dept` can never equal `'Accounting'`.)

This is clearly wrong and so it's no surprise that Oracle hurls ORA-28112. Fortunately the solution is equally clear: just tidy the assignment of `vv_dept`:

```
vv_dept := SYS_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept');
```

The other thing to look at is the formatting on the policy itself. You are testing for equality of a string, so you need to wrap it it in quotes to make valid SQL:

```
        payroll_pred := 'DEPT =''' || vv_dept ||'''';
```

And the same for the other branch, obviously.

One other thing to consider. If you logon as a user who is not in `payroll` table (not sure whether that's possible) you execute this:

```
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
```

Consequently, that session has no context set which means the policy function will fail if the user subsequently tries to query `payroll`. A better approach would be to set the context with a null for `dept`, then in the policy add a test for `vv_dept is null` which applies `1=2` or something similar.

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Well you'd certainly get that if you were running your posted `sec_fun` code, because you defined `vv_dept` as `varchar2(20)` and the assigned string is longer than twenty characters. But you say you are running my suggested revisions, so it can't be that. What is the size of `payroll.dept`?

Last word.

VPD policies are just a special case of dynamic SQL, and the core teaching remains: dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. Likewise the main debugging tool is still writing an execution handle which logs the whole assembled string to a table (or file).

---

Incidentally, I think there's a flaw in the business logic. As it stands now nobody can look at the records for the Accounting department (except for power users with the `EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY` privilege).

Comment: thank you a lot for replying,
I've edited the code as you said, but the error is still there.
Are there any other suggestions??
thank you in advance

Comment: And i also understood the flaw you mentioned the business logic, but this is the policy asked to perform

Comment: Sorry but still no luck!

Comment: I have edited my policy function as you said above.
If you can read it one more time please

Comment: Policy function execution error:
Logon user     : SYS
Table/View     : PCM.PAYROLL
VPD Policy name    : PAYROLL_POLICY
Policy function: ANNE.SEC_FUN
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "ANNE.SEC_FUN", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1

*** 2018-12-17 12:40:00.701
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "APEX_040200"."ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE"
ORA-28112: failed to execute policy function
ORA-06512: at "ANNE.PAYROLL_CTX_PKG", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: If you may in your free time check the edited version of this question after doing what you suggested, It would be amazing thank you for your time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816394/vpd-policy-function-modified