# VPD policy function Modified

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

**Hello, I have asked this question yesterday but thanks to your help, I did a lot of modifications so now I'm putting the new version of my code because it's getting better but still not working.**

Let's assume i have the following table which is called `payroll` created by a user called `PCM`

```
EMP_ID               DEPT                      TOTAL      TAXES
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
E1                   accounting                 2400        100 
E2                   sales                      2500         75 
E3                   research                   3000        110 
E4                   operations                 4200        120 
E5                   sales                      4800        130 
E6                   sales                      2500         75 
E7                   accounting                 5200        140 
E8                   accounting                 2700        105
```

Now what i want to achieve is the following: Anyone with the `dept = accounting"` can select all other rows with `dept != accounting` but anyone with `dept != accounting` can only view his/her record.

Now I'm connected as another user not the owner of the payroll table so I'm connected as a user called `ANNE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT payroll_ctx USING payroll_ctx_pkg;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE payroll_ctx_pkg IS 
  PROCEDURE set_dept;
 END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY payroll_ctx_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE set_dept
  AS
    v_dept varchar2(400);
  BEGIN
     SELECT dept INTO v_dept FROM PCM.PAYROLL
        WHERE EMP_ID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');
     DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept', v_dept);
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx', 'dept', 'NO');
  END set_dept;
END;
/
```

Considering that the users who will try to access the table have the names of the emp_id column,now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_dept_trig AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
 BEGIN
  ANNE.payroll_ctx_pkg.set_dept;
 END;
/
```

Now the problem(i know it's wrong) but can't find the solution yet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE security_package AS 
FUNCTION sec_fun (D1 VARCHAR2, D2 VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2; 
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY security_package AS 
FUNCTION sec_fun (D1 VARCHAR2, D2 VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    vv_dept varchar2(400);
    V_ID varchar2(400);
begin
    V_ID := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');
    vv_dept := 'SYS_CONTEXT(''payroll_ctx'', ''dept'')';
    if (vv_dept != 'accounting') then
    RETURN 'EMP_ID = ' || CHR(39)||V_ID||CHR(39);
    ELSE
    RETURN 'DEPT != ' || CHR(39)||vv_dept||CHR(39);
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
    RETURN '1 = 0';
end sec_fun;
end security_package;
/
```

And Finally:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
  object_schema    => 'PCM', 
  object_name      => 'PAYROLL', 
  policy_name      => 'payroll_policy', 
  function_schema  => 'ANNE',
  policy_function  => 'security_package.sec_fun',
  statement_types  => 'select');
END;
/
```

Now when a user `E1` tries to select from payroll the output is:

```
EMP_ID               DEPT                      TOTAL      TAXES
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
E1                   accounting                 2400        100
```

what I'm doing wrong?? It's supposed to return all rows where `dept != accounting`

Comment: I think you meant `v_id := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');` in your sec_fun function, not `v_id := user;`. That's what you're using in your predicate in the set_dept procedure to find the dept for the specific emp_id, anyway

Comment: Yes , I Tried it also but It's the same result, any other suggestions??

Comment: if you run the security_package.sec_fun function on its own, what is the output you get?

Comment: I did the following Modification:

      `vv_dept := 'SYS_CONTEXT(''payroll_ctx'', ''dept'')';`

and now when I run the security_package.sec_fun as the following :

`select security_package.sec_fun('PCM','payroll') from dual;`

the output is:

`EMP_ID = 'ANNE'`

Comment: Now when E1 write the statement:

`select * from PCM.payroll;`

only his row is returned which is still wrong.

Comment: so can you take another look at the code please??

Comment: What does `select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual;` return when you're running as E1? Also, if I were you, I'd change the logic of your function to check if the dept is accounting, otherwise defaulting to return just the logged-in employee's row.

Comment: `select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual;`
The result is:
E1
and i changed the logic for the function

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask what `select sys_context('payroll_ctx', 'dept') from dual;` returned after you were logged in as E1.

Comment: It returns `accounting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your helping i finally managed to solve the problem, It was in the variable vv_dept when i made the following modifications it worked out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE security_package AS 
FUNCTION sec_fun (D1 VARCHAR2, D2 VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2; 
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY security_package AS 
FUNCTION sec_fun (D1 VARCHAR2, D2 VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    V_ID varchar2(400);
begin
    V_ID := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');
    if (SYS_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx','dept') = 'accounting') then
    RETURN 'DEPT != ' || CHR(39)||SYS_CONTEXT('payroll_ctx','dept')||CHR(39);
    ELSE
        RETURN 'EMP_ID = ' || CHR(39)||V_ID||CHR(39);
  END IF;
    EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
    RETURN '1 = 0';
end sec_fun;
end security_package;
/
```